# Visual studio builds different projects to same location

Tags: visual-studio, build, path, visual-studio-2019

I have 2 projects in one solution (c++), but both of them build into the same place, the 2nd one builds into the debug folder of the first one. How can i make each one build into it's own place?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open solution exploler.
2. Right click on the project which you want to change the build location.
3. Select properties.
4. Goto Build.
5. Change the Output path.